# Quick Integral Approximation Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So, I was studying for a test and I came across this problem:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Sorry for the disorganized format, but it seemed like a lot of info to throw into text. I'm a bit confused on how I'd go about finding the answer here, I understand how to integrate and derive, but I'm a bit lost on how I'd go about accomplishing this problem.

Comment: Have you tried the substiution $u=x^2-1$?

Comment: I'm confused, how would that help me get a value for the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2-1$ then $du=2xdx$. Evaluating u on the limit points the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_3^8 f'(u)du.
$$
What can you say now using the graph given?

Comment: Ok, so using this method would I just evaluate the integral since it was put in terms of $u$? So would the answer be somewhere around $-2.5$?

Comment: This is just a dummy variable. $\int_3^8 f'(u)du=\int_3^8 f'(x)dx$. And it is the area under your curve $f'$. So, $\int_3^8 f'(u)du=5-10=-5$.